# jFreeChart: Setting different positive and negative standard deviations on a bar chart

Tags: jfreechart

I need to create a StatisticalBarChart that not just has one value for standard deviation but a positive and negative standard deviation.
So that the deviation is not symmetrical around the mean value.
This is how it's supposed to look:

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-07-25%20um%2014.05.11.JPG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-07-25%20um%2014.05.11.JPG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to extend `BarRenderer` to override `drawItem()` and extend `AbstractDataset` to provide the extra data, as suggested in the [*PLSNPAIRS*](http://code.google.com/p/plsnpairs/) classes, [`AsymmetricStatisticalBarRenderer`](http://code.google.com/p/plsnpairs/source/browse/branch/charisa/extern/AsymmetricStatisticalBarRenderer.java?spec=svn1178&r=1096) and [`AsymmetricStatisticalCategoryDataset`](http://code.google.com/p/plsnpairs/source/browse/branch/grigori/extern/AsymmetricStatisticalCategoryDataset.java?r=1223).